# How to get the list of occurence in list of object reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm having trouble with arrays of object in React.js. I have a list of objects like this :

```
const list = [ 
{ name: name1,
 age: age1,
 address: addresse1
},
{ name: name2,
 age: age2,
 address: addresse2
},
{ name: name1,
 age: age1,
 address: addresse4
},
{ name: name3,
 age: age3,
 address: addresse3
}]
```

How can I get an array with every different names like that ?

```
['name1','name2','name3']
```

I tried by mapping the list and set a bool but I can't figure how to loop and compare list[i] and list[i+1] in mapping function

Comment: What you have tried so far in code post that also

Answer (score 0):

You can map array to make an array of names and after that [leave only unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

```js
const list = [ 
{ name: 'name1',
 age: 'age1',
 address: 'addresse1'
},
{ name: 'name2',
 age: 'age2',
 address: 'addresse2'
},
{ name: 'name1',
 age: 'age1',
 address: 'addresse4'
},
{ name: 'name3',
 age: 'age3',
 address: 'addresse3',
}]

const result = [...new Set(list.map(item => item.name))]

console.log({ result })
```